# ArrayList references to objects

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm a little confused on what it means about ArrayLists holding references to objects. Can someone give me an example on how this is shown in code? Also, can arraylist have an element that is a reference to itself? Thanks!

Comment: Do you generally know, what references are?

Comment: I believe a reference is an object referring to something.. for example.. String hello = new String(); hello is a reference to a string object. am i correct?

Comment: Tom's question is a good one, but I will say that in Java we don't usually distinguish between "references to objects" and "objects". If someone told me that a list held "references to objects", I would just take that as a reminder that if the object is changed outside of the list, so is the object in the list: they are the same object.

Comment: Is this a homework question? This is a pretty fundamental question.

Comment: @swordhunter2000 A reference refers to an object. So if you would call `list.add(hello);` and then `String anotherString = list.get(0);`, then `hello` and `anotherString` would both refer to the same String object, because they share the same reference. This also shows that a list won't copy the passed object of the `add` method. It just store its reference. And it will return that reference if you access it using `get(index)`.

Comment: If you are not technically minded, then you can think of references as handles to an object or better even an address of where an object is located in memory.

Answer (score 1):

You have to start making distinctions between variables, values, and objects.

Variables are containers. They contain values.

Values can be of two types, primitive and reference. Reference values are pointers to objects.

Objects are data structures which also have behavior.

So in

```
Object var = new Object();
```

`var` is a variable. `new Object()` is a new instance creation expression that evaluates to a value of type `Object`, that value is a reference to an object of type `Object`. That value is then assigned to `var`.

You can then use `var` to invoke a method

```
var.toString();
```

The runtime environment will evaluate `var`, which produces a reference value, retrieve the referenced object, and invoke the method. You can reassign the value stored in `var` by doing

```
var = someOtherValue;
```

Now `var` will hold a new value.

An `ArrayList` uses an array behind the scenes. An array is a special object where its elements (which you can think of as fields) are themselves variables.

So

```
Object[] arr = new Object[10];
```

is an array of type `Object` which contains ten variables. These variables contain values of type `Object`. Again, these values are references. You can evaluate them or you can reassign them.

```
arr[3].toString();
arr[7] = "maybe a string";
arr[9] = arr[9]; // possible, but makes no sense
```

Answer (score 0):

It means instead of copying the object byte-for-byte, a reference to the location of memory where the object is stored is put in the list.

```
List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();
Object myObject = new Object();
objects.add(myObject);
// objects contains one reference to myObject

objects.get(0).modify();
// myObject modified
```

Note that primitive values (`int` for example) will be copied.