# Array of references to ArrayList Object

Tags: java, arraylist, reference

I want to know the shortcut for doing this :

```
class{ ArrayList a1=new ArrayList();
       ArrayList a2=new ArrayList();
       ArrayList a3=new ArrayList();
       .....& so on 
     }
```

So instead of writing each reference, how can I write an array of references 'with ArrayList' ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28423563/arraylist-references-to-objects

Answer (score 1):

```
you can use `List<ArrayList> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();`. In this you can add any number of `ArrayList` Objects to `list` reference.
```

Find the below :

```
List<ArrayList> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();

list.add(new ArrayList());
list.add(new ArrayList());
list.add(new ArrayList());
list.add(new ArrayList());
```

// ....

`list` hold `ArrayList` references in inserted order. You can access the `ArrayList` using index which zero based.

```
// to access the ArrayList reference.
ArrayList a1 = list.get(0);
```

Comment: But problem is not solved with it because then again for adding elements to individual ArrayList I have to use another reference  (as u have used 'a1' here ) for each ArrayList.

Comment: @Singh, the `list.get(n)` is an ArrayList. You can also use it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array of ArrayList. And loop.

```
ArrayList a1, a2, ... , a100;
ArrayList[] arrayLists = new ArrayList[100];

for (ArrayList arrayList : arrayLists) {
    arrayList = new ArrayList();
}
```

Comment: Is there any way without initializing the size ?

Answer (score 0):

But creating different references array is not a good design.
For example you can create array list array like below:

```
ArrayList[] a = new ArrayList[4];
```

Before implementing this you clear with your requirement , why you need to create these many references.

And also while creating `ArrayList` it's better to use reference creation like below:

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Always use **generics** while working on **JAVA collections**.

For your requirement to store word and it's permutations, I would suggest below process:

**Step1:** Create WordPermutations class

```
public Class WordPermutations{
     public string word;
     public ArrayList<String> permutations = new ArrayList<String>();

     public void setWord(String word){
       this.word = word;
      }
     public void setPermutations(ArrayList<string> permutations){
      this.permutations = permutations;
     }
     public String getWord(){
     return this.word;
     }
     public ArrayList<String> getPermuatations(){
     return this.permuations;
     }

}
```

**Step2**: Use this class to create your arrayList objects like below:

```
Class MainPermutation{
public static void main(String args[]){
    // your code to get all your words and their permutations
    // Now add them like below
    ArrayList<WordPermutations> words = new ArrayList<WordPermutations>();
    //your loop to iterate words and their permutations
    for (int i=0;i<words.length;i++){
     WordPermutations wordP = new WordPermutations();
     wordP.setWord(word); //String word
     wordP.setPermutations(permutations); //arraylist of permutations
     words.add(wordP); //adding your word and it's permutations to class
     }
}
}
```

**Step3**: Now read your arrayList array accordingly

with above process you can store n number of words.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I have a file with list of string words. Requirement is to create all permutations of each word and to store all permutations  of each word in separate arrayList.                    Here number of words in the file is not fixed, So how can we create array of reference without initializing the size ?

Comment: I would suggest some other way , you create one class which will store your word and it's permutations, I will update my answer.

Comment: Check my updated answer, no need to mention the size here.